NNStreamer - could not link tensortransform to tensorfilter
I'm using Ubuntu Linux. I would like to run the example pipeline below with a command line.
https://github.com/nnstreamer/nnstreamer-example/blob/main/native/example_pose_estimation_tflite/nnstreamer_example_pose_estimation_tflite.cc
This is the pipeline code I modified to suit me.
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test_mp4/department_store_shopping.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=RGB ! tee name=t_raw t_raw. ! queue leaky=2 max-size-buffers=2 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=257,height=257,foramt=RGB ! tensor_converter ! tensor_transform mode=arithmetic option=typecast:float32,add:-127.5,div:127.5 ! tensor_filter framework=libnnstreamer_filter_tensorflow1-lite model=tflite_model/posenet_mobilenet_v1_100_257x257 ! tensor_decoder mode=pose_estimation option1=640:480 option2=257:257 option3=tflite_model/point_labels.txt option4=heatmap-offset ! compositor name=mix sink_0::zorder=1 sink_1::zorder=0 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink t_raw. ! queue ! mix

**I checked all the environment variables and when I run
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep tensor,
everything prints out fine. However, I'm debugging with fakesink and I'm getting the same error as "could not link tensortransform0 to tensorfilter0" as shown below.**
`** (gst-launch-1.0:10498): WARNING **: 11:58:58.402: Cannot identify the given neural network framework, libnnstreamer_filter_tensorflow1-lite.so
(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_ref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_caps_can_intersect: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps1)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_ref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_ref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_caps_can_intersect: assertion 'GST_IS_CAPS (caps2)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_ref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_pad_template_new: assertion 'caps != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_element_request_compatible_pad: assertion 'GST_IS_PAD_TEMPLATE (templ)' failed

(gst-launch-1.0:10498): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:58:58.405: gst_object_unref: assertion 'object != NULL' failed
0:00:00.014208289 10498 0x55b9ae31ce40 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE subprojects/gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y:774:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link tensortransform0 to tensorfilter0

This is the result of “nnstreamer-check”.
NNStreamer version: 1.7.1
           loaded : TRUE
           path   : /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libnnstreamer.so

NNStreamer configuration:
============================================================
Configuration Loaded: TRUE
Configuration file path: /etc/nnstreamer.ini
    Candidates: envvar(NNSTREAMER_CONF): (null)
                build-config: etc/nnstreamer.ini
                hard-coded: /etc/nnstreamer.ini
[Common]
  Enable envvar: TRUE
  Enable sym-linked subplugins: TRUE
[Filter]
  Filter paths from .ini: /usr/lib/nnstreamer/filters/
             from envvar: (null)
         from hard-coded: /usr/lib/nnstreamer/filters/

============================================================

** (nnstreamer-check:10588): CRITICAL **: 12:09:22.321: nnstreamer_subplugin of cpp(/usr/lib/nnstreamer/filters/libnnstreamer_filter_cpp.so) is broken. It does not call register_subplugin with its init function.

** (nnstreamer-check:10588): CRITICAL **: 12:09:22.322: Cannot open tensor_region(/usr/lib/nnstreamer/decoders/libnnstreamer_decoder_tensor_region.so) with error /usr/lib/nnstreamer/decoders/libnnstreamer_decoder_tensor_region.so: undefined symbol: gst_tensor_meta_info_append_header.

NNStreamer registered sub-plugins:
============================================================

[Filter]

[Decoder]

[Conterver]

============================================================
I really don't know. How do I solve this?


Update the pipeline description


framework=libnnstreamer_filter_tensorflow1-lite

==>

framework=tensorflow1-lite


See if libnnstreamer_filter_tensorflow1-lite.so is installed in the proper directory. You may use nnstreamer-check utility.

Run gst-inspect tensor_filter. Look at the framework entry, which lists available frameworks.



From the updated information, I see that you didn't install the built binaries properly. Have you installed your subplugins (e.g., libnnstreamer_filter_tensorflow1-lite.so) to your designated directory (/usr/lib/nnstreamer/filters/). According to your installation directory (/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libnnstreamer.so), it appears that you have installed subplugins to /usr/local/lib..., not /usr/lib/....
For subplugin (frameworks) checks, run gst-inspect tensor_filter, not gst-inspect | grep tensor.
Such discrepancy usually happens when you have installed older versions with apt(dpkg), and then, build and install newer versions without properly configuring (to isolate environments from older installs) or uninstalling corresponding packages.

Configure envvar so that it directs to your newly built subplugins (to /usr/local/...) for filters, converters, and decoders.
or
make a symlink from /usr/lib/nnstreamer to /usr/local/lib/nnstreamer. (this will break the behavior or previous dpkg install)
or
uninstall the old versions.
or
work in a clean docker or chroot.

